# rb_require (and other functions) not working when using Ruby C API (Windows mingw64)

Tags: c, ruby, segmentation-fault, mingw-w64, msys2

After some time trying to propperly link the Ruby Library to my code, I managed how to do it, however I have this issue, whenever I want to require a file with `rb_require()` or to do a `rb_marshal_load()`, it crashes with a Segmentation Fault. I have tested other functions, such as, `rb_eval_string_protect()`and `rb_file_open()` and they work just fine.

The code is something like

```
ruby_init();
ruby_init_loadpath();
ruby_script("XXX");

const char* = "path/to/rb/file"
rb_require(load_path);
```

I'm using mingw64 and the ruby package where I get the lib is [mingw64-x86_64-ruby](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-ruby?repo=mingw64).

The error shown is:

```
ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [x64-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0002 p:---- s:0006 e:000005 CFUNC  :getbyte
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:0025c0 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
XXX:0:in `getbyte'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x14) [0x00007ffb0aa8d0e4]
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll(WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8e) [0x00007ffb08492d1e]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0x216) [0x00007ffaaaac95a6]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_bug_for_fatal_signal+0x84) [0x00007ffaaa91bc14]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_fiber_scheduler_address_resolve+0x1eb) [0x00007ffaaaa3cf7b]
 [0x00007ff762125ac2]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(_C_specific_handler+0x96) [0x00007ffb0aa7c876]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(_chkstk+0x11f) [0x00007ffb0aa923df]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlRaiseException+0x434) [0x00007ffb0aa414a4]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x2e) [0x00007ffb0aa90f0e]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlWaitOnAddress+0xc6) [0x00007ffb0aa53526]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x214) [0x00007ffb0aa1fcb4]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x42) [0x00007ffb0aa1fae2]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_w32_io_cancelable_p+0x3c) [0x00007ffaaaad748c]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_io_getbyte+0xd8) [0x00007ffaaa95dcc8]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_vm_invoke_proc+0x242) [0x00007ffaaaab57f2]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_eval_cmd_kw+0x5c7) [0x00007ffaaaab7dd7]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_funcallv+0x11) [0x00007ffaaaab7f11]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(ruby_init_ext+0x1bc2) [0x00007ffaaa97a7f2]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(ruby_init_ext+0x52e0) [0x00007ffaaa97df10]
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby310.dll(rb_protect+0x155) [0x00007ffaaa9256a5]
 [0x00007ff76212176f]
 [0x00007ff7621212ee]
 [0x00007ff762121406]
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL(BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14) [0x00007ffb08eb7604]
```

The thing is, when compiling the exact same code (with some minor changes in CMakeLists for everything to work as needed) in the Mingw64 terminal and the MSYS2 terminal (not mingw64, using the package [ruby](https://packages.msys2.org/package/ruby?repo=msys&variant=x86_64)), the first one crashes as I said, while in the second one works (I mean `rb_require()` works fine). I also tried to use the library from RubyInstaller and to compile on my own the Ruby source code to get the library, but none of these worked (either not compiling, throwing lots of undefined references, or just crashing whenever I used a function of the API (including `ruby_init()`), but in the end, the only way to make it to work was using one of the packages in MSYS2.

Comment: I'm familiar with Ruby and MSYS2 so I might be able to help, but the code you posted doesn't even have valid C syntax.  Could you post your complete code as a [mcve], along with explicit instructions about how to compile it and reproduce the crash?  CMake shouldn't be needed, you can just invoke GCC directly and maybe call `pkg-config` directly to get the right arguments for GCC.

Comment: While writing that minimal reproducible example, I found that the problem is the dumped file I'm trying to load, this file is a dumped object of a class that I'm requiring (I got the rb_require to work by adding ```ruby_sysinit(&argc, &argv);
    RUBY_INIT_STACK;``` to the beggining of `main` function). I created a test class for the example and everything worked. Is there anyway I can see an error when loading the file I need instead of the segmentation fault to know what is happening?

Comment: There's no general way to convert all segmentation faults into friendly errors, but you could build things with debug symbols and use a debugger like GDB to get clues.   Every library has requirements for how you call it, and checking every single requirement at run time to avoid segmentation faults is not generally possible.  If you want more specific help I still need they [mcve] and you probably need to ask a new question, as this one is solved.